# How to get multiple docs using single query pouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

I am new to pocuhDB,
I want get multiple docs in single query.

This is my documents structure: consider below 4 docs

```
{
"type": "SHIP",
"regNumber": "11"
},

{
"type": "SHIP",
"regNumber": "29"
},

{
"type": "SHIP",
"regNumber": "22"
},

{
"type": "SHIP",
"regNumber": "67"
}
```

I want to get all docs which matches with regNumber i have in other array:
`myArray = ["11","22","67"]`

Expected Output:

```
    {
    "type": "SHIP",
    "regNumber": "11"
    },

    {
    "type": "SHIP",
    "regNumber": "22"
    },

    {
    "type": "SHIP",
    "regNumber": "67"
    }
```

***Thank you in advance !***

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved using pouchDB Mango queries, specifically using the `$in` operator.

Assuming there is a desire to query by both `type` and an arbitrary number of `regNumber` items the strategy is straight forward. First create an index, such as in the snippet:

```
  // create the index
  await db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ['type', 'regNumber'],
      ddoc: "type-regNumber-index"
    }
  });
```

Where `fields` defines the document fields to index; `ddoc` names the index.

Afterwards it's a simple matter to construct a query; again to the snippet,

```
  const query = {
    "selector": {
      "$and": [{
          "type": type
        },
        {
          "regNumber": {
            "$in": regNumbers
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "use_index": "type-regNumber-index"
  }
```

Where `regNumbers` is an array of values,  and `type` a string value.

Run and then read over the code snippet, I've tried to keep it minimal.

```js
// find button click handler
const regNumberQuery = async(type, regNumbers, viewResult) => {
  const query = {
    "selector": {
      "$and": [{
          "type": type
        },
        {
          "regNumber": {
            "$in": regNumbers
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "use_index": "type-regNumber-index"
  }

  // query
  const result = await db.find(query);

  // display results   
  if (result.docs.length) {
    // clean up prior result
    viewResult.innerHTML = '';
    result.docs.forEach(doc => {
      // display doc as a row 
      const pre = creEl('pre');
      pre.innerText = ['type:', type, '\nregNumber:', doc.regNumber].join(' ');
      pre.classList.add('border-bottom');
      viewResult.appendChild(pre);

    });
  } else {
    // no results
    viewResult.innerHTML = '<div>No results.</div>';
  }
  // display the query i.e. selector.
  const pre = creEl('pre');
  pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(query, null, 3);
  viewResult.appendChild(pre);

}

//
//  boilerplate code
//

// canned test documents
const getDocsToInstall = () => {
  return [{
      "type": "SHIP",
      "regNumber": "11"
    },
    {
      "type": "SHIP",
      "regNumber": "29"
    },
    {
      "type": "SHIP",
      "regNumber": "22"
    },
    {
      "type": "SHIP",
      "regNumber": "67"
    }
  ]
}
// init db instance
let db;

const initDb = async() => {

  // create an in-memory db
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });

  // add test docs
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());

  // create the type/regNumber index
  await db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ['type', 'regNumber'],
      ddoc: "type-regNumber-index"
    }
  });
}

// initialize the db then show search controls.
initDb().then(() => {
  getEl(g_view_result).classList.remove('hide')
});


// conveniences
const getEl = id => document.getElementById(id);
const creEl = id => document.createElement(id);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.label {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.hints {
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.find.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>

<table id='view' class=''>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='regNumbersCSV' type='text' value='11,29,22,67' />
      <label class='hints' for='regNumbersCSV'>regNumbers (e.g. 11,29,22,67)</label>
      <div>
        <input id='type' type='text' value='SHIP' />
        <label class='hints' for='type'>Type (e.g. SHIP)</label>
        <div style='margin-top:1em'>
          <button onclick="regNumberQuery(
          getEl('type').value.trim(),
          getEl('regNumbersCSV').value.split(',').map(n => n.trim()),
          getEl('viewResult'))">Find</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style='margin-top:2em'></div>
<div id='viewResult' class='border-top'>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using couchbase use the following query.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM default AS t USE KEYS ["11","22","67"];
```

Comment: Thank you for adding comments. but i want to get docs pragmatically which uses pouchDB

Comment: @KrunalLathia Since you're not using Couchbase, I'll remove all the Couchbase tags on your question.